# Laravel - Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use multi auth in laravel 5.6.

I use linux 16.4. and PHP 7.2

After run `http://localhost:8000/manage/login` and click login button, show this error:

```
"Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Admin given, called in /media/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php on line 380"
```

How to issue this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that your `Admin` model hasn't implemented the `Authenticatable` interface.

Include the following `use` statement in your class and then `implement` it e.g.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class Admin extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {
    ...
}
```

You will then need to make sure that all of the necessary methods are included in your model. The easiest way to do this would be to include the `Authenticatable` trait e.g.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class Admin extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {

    use Authenticatable;
}
```

Lastly, you may need to override some of the methods depending on if you're db table is different from the out-of-the-box `User`.

Comment: Hi Ross. I'm an editor here, and spend a bit of time trimming content and helping present posts in a technical writing format where possible. Editors tend to trim politenesses, since they're not necessary (several refs on _Meta_, [this is the canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776)). In particular, you have 487 "hope this helps" in your post history, and I wonder if you could reduce these a bit? I presume everyone posting an answer hopes it helps, but we don't need 24,578,779 of them `:-)`.

Comment: No worries @Ross `:-)`